# Should I launch "clean install" after "import changes" on Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

On Intellij, every time I'm changing project version, or pulling a new version, it propose me to import project.

[image]

Is that sufficient or should I launch a maven clean install ?
if a maven clean install is needed, so what is the interrest of "Import changes"

Comment: Simply accept that. IDEA handles that. A `mvn clean install` is not necessary most of the times. I recommend to use `Enable Auto-Import` that makes life easier with IDEA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `mvn clean install`. This action synchronizes IntelliJ IDEA project model with the Maven/Gradle project model.

Since 2020.1 version you will not see the notification, it was changed to a pop-up icon.

Comment: @KaderLAB Your question was "Is that sufficient or should I launch a maven clean install?". My answer is exactly to this question: "You don't need mvn clean install". Then I describe what this action does: "This action synchronizes IntelliJ IDEA project model with the Maven/Gradle project model". Then I clarify the change of the behavior in the new IDE versions as you will no longer get this notification. So why a downvote and why my answer is not valid? Maybe you should clarify the question instead?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ should download and add all your dependencies to the project's classpath automatically as long as your POM is compliant and all the dependencies are available.

This import changes dialog box indicates  that if you make any changes to your POM those changes will be loaded automatically.

If that doesn't help you then run `mvn clean install` from the command line.

Comment: May you explain what do you mean by "POM is compliant" ?

Comment: POM is a proper XML adhering to Maven. You can set Intellij to import all changes automatically using  `File > Settings > Maven > Importing >Automatically Download`.